# In Flink, distinguish between uninitialized state and cleared state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In a Flink job, I have a state of type `ValueState<Boolean>`.  This state is set to true when condition is true, and cleared otherwise. I am clearing the state as opposed to setting it to false to reduce size of state.

I want to treat uninitialized state the same as "set to true" state, but without setting the state to "true".  Is there a way to distinguish between uninitialized state and cleared state?

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

Cleared state is removed, and no longer exists. It cannot be distinguished from uninitialized state.

You can’t get the benefits of state without paying for it.